# How to call assign value of label of one form In other class?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am having class

**MainForm.cs** 
where its **MainFormDesigner.cs**

```
 public System.Windows.Forms.Label diffTime;
```

I want this labels value to be assigned in Other class

**Request.cs** class
When I try in these way

```
 MainForm.diff.Text = "Diff:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Tried giving static in MainForm but unable to get label values assigned in other class.

How can I do this, any help on this please.

Comment: Is `Request.cs` another form?

Comment: No its just a class Request.cs class in the same project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Designer of your form, select your label, in properties, select `Modifier` then change the value of modifier to `public`.

Then in other class, **assuming, there you have an instance of your MainForm** do this:

```
//if the variable of instance of your MainForm is mainForm for example:
mainForm.diff.Text = "Diff:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: @ShopShop Show your codes. You should not have anything static, instead you should have an instance of form in your request class –

Comment: After about 6 years :D thanks for the feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

A `cheating` way:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public static System.Windows.Forms.Label diffTime;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        diffTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        diffTime.AutoSize = true;
        diffTime.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(113, 55);
        diffTime.Name = "diffTime";
        diffTime.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        diffTime.TabIndex = 0;
        diffTime.Text = "label1";
        this.Controls.Add(diffTime);
    }
```

then in `Request.cs` you can call `MainForm.diff.Text = "Diff:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

But I recommend you follow Reza Aghaei's answer, you need some variable to hold your MainForm's instance: 
Request.cs:

```
public class Request
{
    public static MainForm mainForm = null;
    public static void setLabelText()
    {
        mainForm.diffTime.Text = "Diff:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

Assuming `MainForm` is called in Program.cs:

```
Request.mainForm = new MainForm(); //pass your instance to Request.cs
Application.Run(Request.mainForm);
```